# Can I create python visual env by python 3.8.1?

Tags: python

I've config my new computer to python env. Now the latest version of python is 3.8, can I create python2 visual env by venv instruction in python 3.8?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to create a virtualenv for Python 3.8?

Comment: What is a "***visual** env*"? Please post exactly what you have tried, cause in some cases it is possible, in others it isn't.

Comment: You can use tools like `pyenv` and `pipenv` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python3 cannot create a Python2 environment.

Python2 is officially end of life anyway, so best to create a Python3 virtualenv

Comment: There are still valid reasons to create Python 2 virtual environments.

Comment: Yes, there are some reasons, but it is better to switch to python3 now !